# Using list comprehensions with different filtering conditions

Tags: python

There is a function that takes the argument as a boolean value

```
def get_choices(retirement):
        choices = [
        {
            'id': id,
            'name': CommonName.build_item_name(
                data
            )
        } for cd, data in _collection.items()
        if not is_used_item(cd)
    ]
```

Now this function works in such a way that its result does not depend on `retirement` value. Is it possible  make it so that the list comp filtering `if not_used_item(cd)` is not applied if `retirement = True` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `retirement or not is_used_item(cd)`, so if `retirement` is `True` the condition is short-circuited and `is_used_item` is not called/evaluated.

```
def get_choices(retirement):
        choices = [
        {
            'id': id,
            'name': CommonName.build_item_name(
                data
            )
        } for cd, data in _collection.items()
        if retirement or not is_used_item(cd)
    ]
```